# Tkinter How can I withdraw and show a window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have successfully made a 'next' and 'back' button for the firstDicePage and secondDicePage functions so that I could return to either of the pages when needed. However, I am trying to avoid making multiple pages pop up every time I hit those buttons. I heard of .withdraw(), but I am unsure how to apply it in this code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog 
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import filedialog 
from tkinter.font import Font
import tkinter as tk
import from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter
import sys
import random


def firstDicePage():

         firstWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(window)  # Create new window.

         firstWindow.title("Dice Roller Generator")

         # Change Icon photo
         image = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\alexi\\Desktop\\Project Photos\\Dice logo.png")
         firstWindow.iconphoto(False, image)

         # Center 
         app_width = 900
         app_height = 600


         screen_width = firstWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
         screen_height = firstWindow.winfo_screenheight()

         x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
         y= (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

         firstWindow.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

         Label(firstWindow, text = "\n\nSelect How Many Dice You Want to Roll!", font='Helvetica 16 bold').pack()

         img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Dice.png"))
         my_label = Label(firstWindow, image=img)
         my_label.img = img  # Save reference to image.
         my_label.pack()

         counter = tkinter.IntVar()

         def increase():
                   counter.set(min(10, counter.get() + 1))

         def decrease():
                   counter.set(max(0, counter.get() - 1))

         lbl = Label(firstWindow, textvariable = counter, font='Helvetica 16 bold')
         lbl.place(x=450, y=330)

         btn1 = Button(firstWindow, text="+", font='Helvetica 16 bold',  padx = 8, pady = 5, command = increase, fg="dark green", bg = "white")
         btn1.place(x=499, y=320)

         btn2 = Button(firstWindow, text ="-", font='Helvetica 16 bold', padx = 11.1, pady = 5, command = decrease, fg="dark green", bg = "white")
         btn2.place(x=375, y=320)

         btn3 = Button(firstWindow, text = "Next", font='Helvetica 16 bold', command=lambda: secondDicePage())
         btn3.place(x = 800 , y = 530)


def secondDicePage():

         secondWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(window)  # Create new window.

         secondWindow.title("Dice Roller Generator")

         # Change Icon photo
         image = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\alexi\\Desktop\\Project Photos\\Dice logo.png")
         secondWindow.iconphoto(False, image)

         # Center 
         app_width = 900
         app_height = 600

         screen_width = secondWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
         screen_height = secondWindow.winfo_screenheight()

         x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
         y= (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

         secondWindow.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

         btn3 = Button(secondWindow, text = "Back", font='Helvetica 16 bold', command=lambda: firstDicePage())
         btn3.place(x = 30 , y = 530)


def secondButton():
    
         # Toplevel object which will
         # be treated as a new window
         secondWindow = Toplevel(window)

         secondWindow.title("Dice Roller Generator")

         # Change Icon photo
         img = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\alexi\\Desktop\\Project Photos\\Dice logo.png")
         secondWindow.iconphoto(False, img)

         # Center 
         app_width = 600
         app_height = 400

         screen_width = secondWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
         screen_height = secondWindow.winfo_screenheight()

         x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
         y= (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

         secondWindow.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

         # A Label widget to show in top-level
         Label(secondWindow, text = "\n\nSelect What/How Many Dice You Want to Roll!", font='Helvetica 16 bold').pack()


# Create the window(root interface)
window = Tk()

# Create a title
window.title("Dice Roller Generator")

# Change Icon photo
img = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\alexi\\Desktop\\Project Photos\\Dice logo.png")
window.iconphoto(False, img)

# Center 
app_width = 600
app_height = 400

screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
y= (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

window.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

# Create a label widget 
lbl = Label(window, text = "\n\n\nChoose the Kind of Die You Want to Roll", font='Helvetica 16 bold')

#Packing(size), Shove it in the screen
lbl.pack()


btn1 = Button(window, text = "Regular Dice", padx = 15, pady = 15, command = firstDicePage)
btn1.place(x=145, y=130)


btn2 = Button(window, text = "D&D Dice", padx = 20, pady = 15, command = secondButton)
btn2.place(x=355, y=130)

btn3 = Button(window, text="Exit", padx = 15, pady = 5, command = window.quit)
btn3.place(x=275, y=335)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For your case, you need to *destroy* the current window instead of *withdraw it* before opening new window.